# How to discover devices like Google TV and Nexus-Q using MediaRoute API on Android?

Tags: android, google-tv, chromecast

I can discover a chromecast by following the tutorial provide by Google here: https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial

Then I observed apps written by Google like Google Music and YouTube. These apps can not only discover chromecast but also other online streamers like NexusQ and Google TV through the same MediaRouteButton.

Can anyone tell me how discover all devices in LAN just like Google dose?
Can I use MediaRouteButton or MediaRoute to do so?

Comment: How's about your research? I have the same issue as you. Can you use MediaRouteButton to discover all Chromecast, Google TV and Smart TV supporting DIAL

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my DIAL app that I have open sourced: https://github.com/entertailion/DIAL

This will discover Google TV and ChromeCast devices, in fact any device that is a DIAL server on the local network.

You can read up about the DIAL spec: http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-protocol-specification

Comment: Is there a way we can do the discovery annoucement? Suppose, i have an android device, which currently is not visible to cast senders. How can i make it visible to a sender app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create / provide a [MediaRouteProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouteProvider.html).  Google TV's can be found using [mDNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762).  Of course, you will need something on the other end to talk to once you've found them.

Comment: None that I'm aware of.